# DLL hell and deployment: best practice for native windows applications

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get a handle on which DLLs my native mode C++ win32 application uses. This isn't always obvious - I can link a library but it's somewhat more difficult to find out which system DLLs are needed, particularly if they're system DLLs.
As a case in point, I recently sent a test build to a remote member of my team who's running an older version of windows.

his machine complained about
'api-ms-win-core-misc-l1-1-0.dll' being missing (I assume this had something to do with my using 'GetSystemTime' and related functions but that's part of my problem: how do I tell?) but seeing as this is a windows system file, how can I package up an installer that will ensure these files are installed?

Also, I've used dependency walker and 'listdlls.exe' to find all the DLLs used by my program but dependency walker can't load that DLL and 'listdlls' seems to silently ignore it, so I can't find their location in order to redistribute them (which feels like the wrong approach anyway).

My question therefore is what's the current best practice to:

- comprehensively determine all the system DLLs that are used by my
  application
- write an installer that ensures these libraries are
  installed on a users machine
- Find out which redistributable installers are needed from a given list of DLLS

I would have thought that installing a visual studio redistributable
   package (e.g.
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
   would be enough. To my knowledge, the team member has installed this
   but still gets DLL issues.

Comment: api-ms-* DLLs do not implement anything, they have no code. They can be avoided by not playing Microsoft's game and just linking with kernel32 and friends instead.

Comment: In your visual studio project, what's your [target platform version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf2Cu.png)? Is your remote team member using that OS version or later?

Comment: Your program has a dependency on ucrtbase.dll.  It is a system component delivered through Windows Update.  So your team member probably used a very old version of Windows that was never updated.  Trying to still support Windows 2000 is not wise, but if you absolutely have to then you can find the deployable items in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt directory.

Comment: Dependency Walker used to be a fine tool. Ten years ago. As of Windows 8, it is rendered useless. If you need to find out, which libraries to deploy, have a look at the documentation: [Deploying Native Desktop Applications (Visual C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/deploying-native-desktop-applications-visual-cpp). Depending on how you look at it, the current state is - more or less - worse, or better, than DLL hell. It's a management issue, still, although the tools to deal with it have changed.

Comment: read the docs, Just because a file is part of system now does not mean it is in Windows to start with. Also, the same runtime could install different dlls on different versions of Windows.  You should only check direct dependencies. Dependencies of system components or runtimes are not yours to worry about.

Comment: If "test build" means "debug build" then installing `visual studio redistributable package` won't help because those are for release builds. The team member will need to install VS2017 to run debug builds or you need to bundle debug runtime along with the executable. Also dependency management should be done in the opposite manner: all the required dlls should be known apriori.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - it's been a while since I've been personally responsible for deploying something this complex (with lots of dependencies) on windows and it's obvious things have changed.
The team member had a very old version of windows (vista) and he's now updating it to windows 7.  I'm on an up-to-date windows 10 but I'd like to be able to target as many windows versions as possible.
@Anders: Linking to kernel32 directly sounds interesting. Is that on top of existing dependencies and what will that achieve?

Comment: Before Win7, the base DLLs were (excluding ntdll) kernel32, user32 and gdi32, there was no such thing as api-ms-* and everyone linked to kernel32 directly for GetSystemTime etc. Microsoft is moving to a model with more layers but there is no benefit for 3rd-party developers to play this game. Microsoft has already messed up the api-ms-* file scheme and had to issue a patch for older systems. Having kernel32.lib early in your linkers command line should take care of most issues for your .exe but the CRT might also link to DLLs that link to api-ms-* files (depending on your compiler/VS version).

Comment: Use static linking to avoid dll hell.